# How to use the context variable in ajaxSetup with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple forms on one page and i am submitting them via Ajaxform plugin like this

```
<td>  <form> form1 </form> </td>
<td>  <form> form2 </form>  </td>
```

---

```
var options = {
            target:        '.ajaxMessage',  
            dataType: 'json',  // pre-submit callback 
            success:     function(data, statusText, xhr, form){ myResponse(data,form)},
            context: { element: this},

            cache: false,
            delegation: true,
            type: 'POST'   }; 

            $(".rform").ajaxForm(options);
```

In mY AjaxSetup , i have this

```
beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){

        $this = settings.context.element;       
        alert($this);
```

But its not working , alert says window object

Comment: `<form1>` is your actual tag, or is that just an example?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Well, what does `this` refer to in `context: { element: this}`?

Comment: basically i want to have current form in context so that i can get it in before send . i also know this is not working but what else i can write there. Because i have the ajaxloader before that form which i want to hide and show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating options, "this" is referring to window.

Not sure what you want `this` to refer to in `beforeSend`, but it would probably be easiest to just set it to a jQuery reference... like so:

```
<form id="form1">...</form>
<form id="form2">...</form>
```

and for your context object:

```
context: { element: $('#form2') },
```

**Updated after Comment**
I see.  This isn't elegant, but you can use the plugin's `beforeSubmit` callback to set a global variable to the form (which is passed into that callback,) and then access that in your `beforeSend` callback.

It might even be better to just put your code in `beforeSubmit` callback.

(this all assumes you're using [this ajaxForm plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object).)

**Updated with Example:**

```
var options = {
  ...
  beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
     // save the form somewhere we can get it later:
     $.MyActiveForm = $form;
  }
```

Now in your onSend function you can access `$.MyActiveForm`

But, I still think you're better off just doing whatever you were going to do in the `onSend` function, in `beforeSubmit`, unless you need to intervene at that particular point.

Comment: I can't hard code the formid because  i want o a0pply this to aal form submits.

Comment: I am using that plugin. but i didn't understand what u mean. Can you give me code example what you have said

Comment: Glad that worked =)  I use that trick A LOT.  I usually have one object sitting in the jQuery object that acts as a namespace for all my garbage (and sometimes, I throw stuff in there just so I can look at it on the console...)  For instance, `$.mystuff = {}`... Now in the console, you can type `$.mystuff` and see your object with all of its children.